# Extract dataframe into multiple subsets based on indices

Tags: r, indexing, subset

I have a dataframe with a large number of columns. I would like to split up the dataframe at the columns based on a beginning index and an end index. These index values are currently stored in a vector as such:

1   18   19   25   26   33   34   41   42   49...

Thereafter, I want to add the first data frame (columns 1 - 18) to all other dataframes (without doing it manually).

Comment: You will get a better response if you have the data you are starting with, what the desired output should be like, what you have tried, and the issues with what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

One of approaches is to tranform your split vector into 2-column matrix than apply it to  a `data.frame` of interest. As a result you will get a list of data frames you wanted.

```
# Simulataed data frame with 100 columns
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:1000, ncol = 100))

# Splits vector
splits <- c(1, 18, 19, 25, 26, 33, 34, 41, 42, 49, 50, 100)

# Extract columns we need to add to the rest of split data frames
first <- splits[1:2]
rest <- splits[-(1:2)]

# create a matrix with two columns
splits_m <- matrix(rest, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)

# make list of data frame base on splits
dfl <- apply(splits_m, 2, function(x) df[, c(x[1]:x[2], first[1]:first[2])])

# access the first data.frame
dfl[[1]]
```